# How to create animations of several sprite sheets based on user actions in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, sprite-sheet

I have 5 sprite sheets that each pertain to a certain action. They are:
idle, run, jump, attack, and dead. Each sprite sheet contains 10 frames for the animation. I'm trying to figure out how to write the code in javascript so that if the player isn't moving the character it uses the idle sprite sheet, if he presses the arrow right or left it uses the run, if he uses the spacebar it uses the jump, etc.

This is for a game I'm creating in HTML5 canvas, thanks!

Comment: Here's my current javascript, sorry I'm pretty novice with js. http://pastebin.com/YbJdaBW6

Comment: can you create a jsFiddle for this please?

Comment: Sure - https://jsfiddle.net/nf9qgqov/

Comment: apparently, images are not loading at my end. I suggest put them on dropbox and use the public link of them?